# Response.BinaryWrite calls the ASPX page twice

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to open a file in the browser using `BinaryWriter`. This causes the a dialog window to open and prompt the user to save or open the file. That behavior is fine; however, if I select open, the aspx page is called again and after a long wait the file finally opens.

I set the ContentType

```
Response.BinaryWrite(binary);
Response.End();
Repsonse.Close();
```

This behavior only occurs with excel and word files.

Browser IE8

Comment: Which browser? What content type are you setting?

Comment: This seems entirely on the browser side.  It would seem the browser is re-requesting your URL if you select open.  There's nothing you can do about that if that's what the browser is doing.

Comment: @PeterRitchie you seem to be correct.  MS Office Apps perform a second request; however, pdf and other types do not.

Answer (score 1):

A substitute way of doing the same. You can check it out:

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(yourFilePath);    
context.Response.Clear();   
context.Response.ContentType = contentType;   //Set the contentType
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFilename(yourFilePath));   
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());       
context.Response.TransmitFile(yourFilePath);
```

Hope this will help